# Why do I see read-write error message when creating a table or inserting rows?

Tags: questdb

I keep getting a "**could not open read-write messages**" when creating a table or inserting rows?

*2022-10-21T17:27:11.336011Z I i.q.c.l.t.LineTcpMeasurementScheduler could not create table [tableName=cpu, ex=could not open read-write*

*io.questdb.cairo.CairoException: [22] could not open read-only [file=/root/.questdb/db/cpu/service.k]*

I have tried the troubleshoot solution given in QuestDB forums but it does not work.
If you could explain why it does not work along with the solution, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possibilities for insufficient limits for the maximum number of open files. Try and change that limit for your device. You can check more about that [here](https://questdb.io/docs/operations/capacity-planning/#maximum-open-files)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the syntax which you used was incorrect. Have you checked, whether the table was created properly or not ?
If not, create the table

`CREATE TABLE my_table(symb SYMBOL, price DOUBLE, ts TIMESTAMP, s STRING) timestamp(ts);`

After creating the table properly, then try to insert the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely hitting a bug which was fixed recently:
https://github.com/questdb/questdb/pull/2627

The fix will be released in the upcoming 6.5.4 release.
Unfortunately not out yet.
Please, try 6.5.4 when it is released, should be out in the next few days.

Comment: 6.5.4 was released today